# Swiftmailer symfony2.2 always sent 0 emails

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have the following swiftmailes config

```
# config.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: stmp
    host:      mail.domain.com
    port:      25
    username:  myuser
    password:  mypass
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"
    logging:  "%kernel.debug%"
```

and the following code for send message

```
$subject = "TESTING";

$mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom("noreply@domain.com")
    ->setTo("julian.reyes.escrigas@gmail.com")
    ->setBody("Body message");

$mailer->send($message);
```

after send the message this can be founded in `app/cache/dev/swiftmailer/spool` but when i call the command

```
$ app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --message-limit=10 --env=dev
```

all messages in the spool disapear but aren't sent to receiver.

**Note**: I've tried STMP settings with a client (thunderbird) and working properly

---

### Testing

for testing purposes I tried to send messages directly without queue

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom("noreply@domain.com")
    ->setTo("julian.reyes.escrigas@gmail.com")
    ->setBody("Body message");

$mailer->send($message);

$transport  = $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
$transport->start();

// but count alwasy is zero
$count = $transport->send($message);
```

i've tried every combination in the config.yml file

```
auth_mode:  plain / login / null
encryption: tsl / ssl / null
port: 25 / 465
```

from symfony profiler i get

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 14:33:12 -0500
Message-ID: <1370374392.51ae40f8b6202@localtest>
From: noreply@mydomain.com
Subject: TEST
To: julian.reyes.escrigas@gmail.com
Mensaje de prueba de Texto
```

---

### Testing 2

I'm starting to think that may be a problem with the version that I have installed. i've tried without success creating a SMTP transport directly

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject("TEST")
    ->setFrom("noreply@domain.com")
    ->setTo(array("julian.reyes.escrigas@gmail.com"))
    ->setBody("Mensaje de prueba de Texto");


$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.domain.com', 25)
    ->setUsername('noreply@domain.com')
    ->setPassword('THEPASS');

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$transport->start();
// ZERO again
$output->writeln(sprintf("Mensajes enviados: %s", $mailer->send($message)));
```

**Note 2**: I've tried with PHpMailer and sent mails without problem with the same settings, but i want use swiftmailer

**Note 3**: testing on my hosting provider with local settings work fine. but i cant test from my own laptop (dev enviroment) without use a tricky ssh tunnel

```
transport: mail
host: localhost
username: ~
password: ~
```

- PHP 5.4.6
- Symfony 2.2.2
- Swiftmailer 5.0

Comment: no, I thought that adding the option "logging" append info to dev.log but no

Comment: Which smtp client are you tring to use? some of them require a port that isnt standard. Some of them require different authentication. Thunderbird can handle checking these cases automatically which is why that may work and it may not here.

Comment: in thunderbird i disabled encryption and set configuration to manual equal to swiftmailer

Comment: Can you try using telnet?

Comment: Is `%kernel.debug%` true? If yes, you should be able to see the logs in the profiler when not using the queue.

Comment: i've tried `telnet domain 25` and send `HELO` with a correct 250 response.

Comment: I've got the same problem (PHP 5.4.17 & Symfony 2.2.5). Did you solve that?

Comment: I installed STMP on my laptop

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it's not just a typo?

```
transport: stmp
```

=>

```
transport: smtp
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone will look for answer: try setting valid e-mail address in `setFrom()` method; in my case dummy e-mail like "noreply@domain.com" was spooled, but delivery failed. After specifying valid address it sent an e-mail (at last!).